# How to swipe Horizontally in appium Android

Tags: java, android, appium

I need to swipe a element from left to right. How to achieve it.

[Element screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Sv7ktz7GNAJU8KATGoPxBZnRHDC6YHzZ)

I tried:

```
new TouchAction(driver).press(214, 1219).moveTo(854,1199).release().perform();
```

But no luck. Can any one help me to swipe this button from left to right?

Comment: What didn't work? No swipe at all? Not enough of a swipe?

Comment: @MikeCollins  It has not swiped the button.  and didn't throw any error too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard-coding the x and y locations is not the best idea, but if you want to swipe horizontally, the y points should be the same.  They're 20 pixels off in your example.  It probably does not affect the outcome, however.

Here's my method to swipe/scroll:

```
/**
 * This method scrolls based upon the passed parameters
 * @author Bill Hileman
 * @param int startx - the starting x position
 * @param int starty - the starting y position
 * @param int endx - the ending x position
 * @param int endy - the ending y position
 */
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public void scroll(int startx, int starty, int endx, int endy) {

    TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction(driver);

    touchAction.longPress(PointOption.point(startx, starty))
               .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(ofSeconds(1)))
               .moveTo(PointOption.point(endx, endy))
               .release()
               .perform();

}
```

Now I then have other methods that use screen coordinates to determine what the x's and y's should be, and then call the scroll method, like this:

```
/**
 * This method does a swipe right
 * @author Bill Hileman
 */
public void swipeRight() {

    //The viewing size of the device
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();

    //Starting x location set to 5% of the width (near left)
    int startx = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
    //Ending x location set to 95% of the width (near right)
    int endx = (int) (size.width * 0.95);
    //y position set to mid-screen vertically
    int starty = size.height / 2;

    scroll(startx, starty, endx, starty);

}
```

Comment: @SubanDhyako I would have rather you added your line as a suggestion in a comment.  I don't have that line in my code, and it's worked fine without it.  I'm not saying it isn't a valid addition, but I have not tested it with that change, and the answer is being presented as mine.